# Delayed recursive method call with parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

My app loads an image from server. I use SDWebImage for caching. When I try to display the image it shows placeholder image if the image isn't cached already so that I decide to wait if it's not cached.

```
- (void)photoPagesController:(EBPhotoPagesController *)controller
            imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
       completionHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *))handler
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        MyPhoto *photo = self.photos[index];

        [self.manager cachedImageExistsForURL:photo.url completion:^(BOOL isInCache) {

            if (isInCache) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    handler(photo.imageView.image);
                });
            }
            else {
                // Wait 1 second and then call 
                // photoPagesController:imageAtIndex:completionHandler recursively.   
            }  
        }];
    });
```

}

How could I make a recursive call after wait certain amount of time? 
Is there a better way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dispatch_after` try

```
- (void)photoPagesController:(EBPhotoPagesController *)controller
            imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
       completionHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *))handler
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        MyPhoto *photo = self.photos[index];

        [self.manager cachedImageExistsForURL:photo.url completion:^(BOOL isInCache) {

            if (isInCache) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    handler(photo.imageView.image);
                });
            }
            else {
                // Wait 1 second and then call 
                // photoPagesController:imageAtIndex:completionHandler recursively.   
                double delayInSeconds = 1.0;  //Give the delay you want 
                dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
                dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                //This will called after 1 seconds
                [self photoPagesController:controller
                    imageAtIndex:index
                    completionHandler:handler];


              });
            }  
        }];
    });  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked :) How would you prevent it to be called more than n times?

Comment: This code depends on network condition.simple solution is to make add an argument to function like `- (void)photoPagesController:(EBPhotoPagesController *)controller
            imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index.Make condition if it is 3 times than not call recursively do whaterver want
       completionHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *))handler numberCall:(NSInteger)callNo` than pass callNo intially 0 and increment in callNo in block.